# Have to find the total number of rattatas, dittos, and pidgeys caught by pokemon and assign to the variables r, d, and p respectively

Tags: dictionary, nested

```
    '''pokemon = {'Trainer1':
          {'normal': {'rattatas':15, 'eevees': 2, 'ditto':1}, 'water': {'magikarps':3}, 'flying': 
      {'zubats':8, 'pidgey': 12}},
          'Trainer2':
          {'normal': {'rattatas':25, 'eevees': 1}, 'water': {'magikarps':7}, 'flying': {'zubats':3, 
       'pidgey': 15}},
          'Trainer3':
          {'normal': {'rattatas':10, 'eevees': 3, 'ditto':2}, 'water': {'magikarps':2}, 'flying': 
      {'zubats':3, 'pidgey': 20}},
          'Trainer4':
          {'normal': {'rattatas':17, 'eevees': 1}, 'water': {'magikarps':9}, 'flying': {'zubats':12, 
      'pidgey': 14}}}'''

'my answer:'
     '''pokemon.keys()

     pokemon['Trainer1']

​
      {'normal': {'rattatas': 25, 'eevees': 1},
      'water': {'magikarps': 7},
      'flying': {'zubats': 3, 'pidgey': 15}}

    pokemon['Trainer2']
    {'normal': {'rattatas': 25, 'eevees': 1},
     'water': {'magikarps': 7},
     'flying': {'zubats': 3, 'pidgey': 15}}


    pokemon['Trainer3']
    {'normal': {'rattatas': 10, 'eevees': 3, 'ditto': 2},
     'water': {'magikarps': 2},
     'flying': {'zubats': 3, 'pidgey': 20}}'''
```

'but now i am stuck because for me simple answer will be to just add rattatas, dittos, and pidgeys as i can see them. But obviously that is not a technical answer. i am very new to python and learning. Please help me solve it.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through a dictionary like this:

```
for trainer in pokemon:
    # loop through keys
    print(trainer)

for trainer in pokemon.keys():
    # same as above
    print(trainer)

for types in pokemon.values():
    # loop through values
    print(types)

for trainer, types in pokemon.items():
    # loop though key,value pairs
    print(trainer + " has " + str(types))
```

Now we just need to loop through `pokemon` and use nested for loops to get to an individual pokemon count and add them up:

```
r = 0
d = 0
p = 0

for trainer, types in pokemon.items():
    # now we can loop over a trainer's caught types
    for type_group, pokemon_counts in types.items():
        # now we can loop over the count of each pokemon in a type caught by the trainer
        for name, count in pokemon_counts.items():
            if name == "rattatas":
                r += count
            elif name == "ditto":
                d += count
            elif name == "pidgey":
                p += count

print("Rattata: " + str(r))
print("Ditto: " + str(d))
print("Pidgey: " + str(p))
# Rattata: 67
# Ditto: 3
# Pidgey: 61
```

The nested loop can be simplified to this because you don't need the first 2 keys, but if you're just starting out it may be easier to understand the above loop:

```
for types in pokemon.values():
    for pokemon_counts in types.values():
        for name, count in pokemon_counts.items():
            if name == "rattatas":
                r += count
            elif name == "ditto":
                d += count
            elif name == "pidgey":
                p += count
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
r,d,p = 0,0,0
for v in pokemon.values():
    for v2 in v.values():
        r=r+v2.get('rattatas',0)
        d=d+v2.get('ditto', 0)
        p=p+v2.get('pidgey', 0)

print("Rattatas:{}, Ditto:{}, Pidgey:{}".format(r,d,p))
# Rattatas:67, Ditto:3, Pidgey:61
```